# Setter property for collection

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a static setter property for a collection, but this does not run when I assign the value. This property does not put the value in a private variable but calls to static method `getVariable()` and `SetVariable(value)` to store the value in the database .

```
public static SessionStateItemCollection session {
    get {
        return getVariableSesion();
    }
    set {
        setVariableSesion(value);
    }
}
```

I call the get property in this way and I returned the collection is in the database

```
Variable = Obj.getVariable["IDENTIFICACION"];
```

The question is, at what point the property setter for the item in the collection I'm adding runs .

I have attached the code for assign the new value

```
Obj.setVariable["IDENTIFICACION"] = "123456";
```

stay tuned and thanks

Comment: Not 100% clear on what you are asking. Can you post the two methods that you are using in the get and set declarations?  Are you trying to get and set values from a instance version or a static variable?

Comment: I do not see where session = SOMETHING. Can you show the code that calls this static property